# Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))

Tags: node.js, express, router, nodemon

one question. I am making an api with node,express and mysql.
And there seems to be an error when I run nodemon.
If anyone knows anything, it would be appreciated.

Error:
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))

My index.js:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const routes = require("./routes/transactions")

//Settings
app.use('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)

//Middlewares
app.use(express.json())

//Routes
app.use("/", routes.transactions)

 //Crear servidor con el puerto
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Hola Mundo', app.get('port'))
})

module.exports = app;
```

My routes/transactions.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mysqlConnection = require('../database');

router.get('/transactions', (req, res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM transactions', (err, rows, fields) => {
        if(!err) {
            res.json(rows)
        } else {
            console.error(err)
        }
    });
});

exports.transactions = router
```

My database.js

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({

   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: '',
   database: 'operations',
   
})

mysqlConnection.connect(function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return
    } else {
        console.log('Db is connected')
    }
})

module.exports = mysqlConnection;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistakenly using `app.use()` instead of `app.set()`.

Change this:

```
app.use('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

to this:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

The error comes because you're passing a string or number to `app.use()` where it expects a middleware function reference.

It seems like you should have had a stack trace for this error (if you learn how to interpret it) that points to the exact line of code (a few steps up the stack) causing the problem which should simplify debugging next time.

Comment: thank you bro, save me :)

Comment: @alexmorales - Since it look like you may be new here, if this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark (not the arrow) to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error here is resulting from the overload of `app.use()`:

You can use this function in two ways, to use middleware and routes.

`routes/transactions.js` should be altered to the following:

```js
const router = express.Router();
const mysqlConnection = require('../database');

router.get('/transactions', (req, res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM transactions', (err, rows, fields) => {
        if(!err) {
            res.json(rows)
        } else {
            console.error(err)
        }
    });
});

exports.transactions = router
```

In `index.js`:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const routes = require("./routes/transactions")

//Settings
app.use('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)

//Middlewares
app.use(express.json())

//Routes
app.use("/", routes.transactions)

 //Crear servidor con el puerto
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Hola Mundo', app.get('port'))
})

module.exports = app;
```

This would run the code in the 'get' endpoint in 'routes/transactions.js' when you navigate to `localhost:<port>/transactions`.

Comment: Thanks for answering brother. But no, it doesn't work.
Since yesterday I've been fighting with this and I can't find a solution hahaha

Comment: @alexmorales OK, I think I found the mistake. The above edit should hopefully work!

Comment: It doesn't work i give up .
It's part of a project that I have to deliver on Saturday and it's stalling me.  Thanks bro :)